# How to know if the user force quit app?

Tags: cocoa, macros, nsapplication

In my mac application I am supporting full screen by changing system resolution of the device. And I am resetting back to old resolution if the user switches from full screen to windowed mode or if user quits the app and I need to handle force quit case also.
1. Is there any API or callback which tells the application if the user presses cmd+opt+esc(force quit).
2. Any other way to handle this?

I know in NSApplicaction there is an option to disable force quit([NSApplication setPresentationOptions: NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit]) but instead of disabling it I want to handle force quit event.

Answer (score 3):

The general consensus is that force quit sends a `SIGKILL` ("consensus" as I don't know any Apple documentation that states this, but it is the logical answer). A `SIGKILL` cannot be caught so you cannot do cleanup directly. An alternative is to run a helper application which monitors you main app and does the cleanup, the main app can terminate the helper on normal exit. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360761/how-to-do-a-cleanup-after-sigkill).

Comment: If you must leave force quit enabled and handle it, a helper application seems like the way to go.